# Correctly typing a function that can return a provided default value

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a function of the following structure:

```py
def get_something_from_data(data: Mapping[str, str], default: Optional[str] = None) -> Optional[str]:
    """Get something out of `data` if it is there, if not return the value of `default`. 
    If `default` is not provided, return None.
    """
```

So this can return either `Optional[str]` if `default` is omitted, or will always return `str` if `default` has an `str` value.

Now I call this in code similar to:

```py
has_value = get_something_from_data(data, "fallback")
return has_value.endswith("k")
```

Even though in this case `has_value` will *always* be an `str`, running `mypy` on this code generates an error because it thinks `has_value` might be `None` and will not have `endswith`.

So I tried typing my function differently:

```py
DT = TypeVar('DT', str, None)

def get_something_from_data(data: Mapping[str, str], default: DT = None) -> Union[str, DT]:
    pass
```

This works, but now when I call mypy on code like:

```py
has_value = get_something_from_data(data)
return has_value.endswith("k")  # might fail as has_value can be None
```

mypy doesn't throw an error, even though the code is potentially dangerous.

Is there a way to properly type this function so mypy generates errors based on whether or not a default value was provided?

Comment: The obvious workaround would be to have one fn which returns a default, and another which doesn't.  But I admit that's clunky.  Interested to see if anyone solves this.

Comment: Please consider adding `[mypy]` tag to your question, as this would make it easier to sport for users having experience with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [typing.overload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) you can describe multiple combinations of arguments and return types for a function

```
from typing import overload, Mapping, Optional


@overload
def get_something_from_data(data: Mapping[str, str], default: None = None) -> Optional[str]:
    ...


@overload
def get_something_from_data(data: Mapping[str, str], default: str) -> str:
    ...


def get_something_from_data(data, default=None):
    pass
```

Comment: note you'll probably want to type-annotate the last one, otherwise you'll get zero type checking on your implementation